# Как сделать переход из активити в фрагмент?

Tags: activity, android, android-intent, android-fragment

Есть activity, из него нужно перейти во fragment. 
Эта строчка не хочет работать:

```
intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Service.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Что есть что в вышеприведённом куске кода? `MainMenu` — что это? `Activity`, `Fragment`? А `Service`?

Comment: Из Activity в Fragment, значит MainMenu - Activity, Service - Fragment. В моем меню есть и активити и фрагменты, на активити из активити я знаю как переходить, как переходить из активити во фрагмент - нет.

Comment: Ну, мягко говоря, названия классов у вас совсем не очевидные. А класс `Service`, который на самом деле вовсе и не сервис, а фрагмент (да ещё и название вносит путаницу с одноимённым классом из SDK) — так это вообще за гранью добра и зла. Используйте соответствующие суффиксы, хотя бы.

Comment: Ок, в дальнейшем буду писать правильно. 
MainMenu у меня ListView, из него я перехожу на разные классы. Есть активити и есть фрагменты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intent` для открытия `Activity` используется, для перехода во фрагмент надо использовать `FragmentManager`.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Читаем [офф. документацию](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)